# having problems calling a method from controller in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

i'm using playframework with scala and slick.

in my dto (dao) I do this:

```
class processDTO @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]
  with ProcessTemplatesComponent {
  import driver.api._

  private val processTemplates = TableQuery[ProcessTemplates]

  def getAll(): Future[Seq[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = db.run { processTemplates.to[Seq].result }
}
```

and in controller I do this:

```
@Singleton
class ProcessesController @Inject() (processDTO: processDTO,  actionBuilder: ActionBuilders) extends Controller{

  def getProcesses() = actionBuilder.DynamicAction(name = "pureLuck").defaultHandler() {
    request =>
      processDTO.getAll().map(_.map(result => {
      }))
        .map(result => Ok(Json.toJson(result)))
  }
}
```

and now I got this error
[image]

[image]

Comment: what is wrong in copying and pasting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you what you need to know. Adding import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global at the top of your file should fix it.

Comment: thanks, but I think thats not all ;) added a screenshot above with a following error

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to import execution context. PlayFramework has his own context. Add this import *play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._* [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools#Using-the-default-thread-pool)

Also you need to return something from this code of block:

```
_.map(result => {})
```

Currently you return *Unit* which can't be transformed to json.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is the lack of execution context as other had mentioned.

As of your json error, you need to implement a [Write converter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes) to transform your `ProcessTemplatesModel` objects into json.